# Dynamo Error "ConfigError: Missing region in config" when developing Alexa skill locally

Tags: node.js, amazon-dynamodb, aws-lambda, alexa-skills-kit

When developing and debugging Alexa skills locally using [Bespoken Tools](https://bespoken.tools), the error occurs when connecting to Dynamo (using the [Alexa Node.js SDK](https://github.com/alexa/alexa-skills-kit-sdk-for-nodejs)).

The error occurs within the Alexa SDK on the ["get" call to Dynamo](https://github.com/alexa/alexa-skills-kit-sdk-for-nodejs/blob/master/lib/DynamoAttributesHelper.js#L7).

Answer (score 5, accepted):

This error occurs because the region set in the `~/.aws/config` is not properly recognized by the Node.js SDK for AWS.

To work around this, just make an explicit call to configure the region, like so:

```
AWS.config.update({
    region: "us-east-1"
});
```

Be sure to call this before processing any events with the alexa-sdk, i.e., before calling `alexa.execute()`.

Comment: This is correct. Only few SDK's like (Java) have default region (US-EAST) set. Node.js SDK has no region set.

Comment: How to implement this in ask sdk v2 for node.js?

Comment: It is done the same way - here is an example with the ASK Node.js SDKV2: https://github.com/jkelvie/alexa-sample-college-finder-nodejs/blob/master/lambda/custom/index.js#L86